# Docker/nginx автоматический ssl для всех сайтов

Tags: nginx, docker, ssl, letsencrypt

пытаюсь создать такую штуку:
Любой домен может быть привязан юзером к определенному айпи, и после привязки к этому айпи, веб сервер (в моем случае nginx) настраивает для него https подключение (с помощью let's encrypt), возможно ли реализовать такое чудо?